# How to set a variable when a view is loaded using WPF MVVM app?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I have a `UserControl` view which require data to be pulled from the database to set the `ObservableCollection` in order to render a DataGrid.

I want to set the `ObservableCollection` when the `UserControl` is loaded **not** when the view model is constructed. Also, I prefer to asynchronously set the `ObservableCollection` so the `UserContror` opens immediacy then then the data-grid is set when the data becomes available.

In my view model I create a public method called `SetVendors()` which fetches the data from the database and sets `ObservableCollection` just before the view is notified. However, I am using the view class directly to set the `SetVendors()` method which sound like a bad practice for some reason to me.

**Questions**
Is it possible to set the data on view-load directly from the view-model? If so, how? Also, is it possible to set the data asynchronously so the view loads quick?

Here is my ViewModel code

```
public class VendorsListViewModel : ViewModel
{
    protected IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int ModelsPerPage { get; set; }
    public IPagedList PageMeta { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<Vendor> _Vendors { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Vendor> Vendors
    {
        get
        {
            return _Vendors;
        }
        set
        {
            _Vendors = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public VendorsListViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        : base()
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        CurrentPage = 1;
        ModelsPerPage = 20;
    }

    public VendorsListViewModel()
        : this(new UnitOfWork())
    {
    }

    public void SetVendors()
    {
        var vendors = UnitOfWork.Vendors.Get(CurrentPage, ModelsPerPage);
        Vendors = new ObservableCollection<Vendor>(vendors);
        PageMeta = vendors.GetMetaData();
    }
}
```

This is how currently set the data from the code behind the view which sound like a bad practice to me.

```
public partial class Index : UserControl
{
    public Index()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // This event is called from the view when the form is loaded using `Loaded="ViewLoaded"` XAML code
    private void ViewLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (DataContext as VendorsListViewModel).SetVendors();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any MVVM framework?

Comment: @Isma no framework. I am using MVVM design pattern as you can see in my view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the data from the view´s code behind is indeed a bad practice as you are breaking the MVVM separation of concerns.

A better way to do that would be using a command, or, more precisely an event to command, check [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx) for a nice explanation.

To achieve this you can use the **System.Windows.Interactivity** library that comes with **Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .NET**, if you don't have it just run the Visual Studio installer and select it.

Then add a reference to the library by going to Add reference -> Assemblies -> Extensions.

Once you have this, things are simple really, you need to just:

First add the namespace to your View:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Then, bind the event to a command in your view model like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Now in your ViewModel we have a little problem, we need to provide a command to be called when the event is triggered, a command is an implementation of the `ICommand` interface, all MVVM frameworks out there will provide you with ready to roll `ICommand` implementations so you can either use one of these frameworks or you can implement `ICommand` yourself if you just need it for this particular example, wait! you don't need to implement it, you can just get it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494035/how-do-i-go-about-using-invokecommandaction-to-call-a-method-of-mine-and-pass-in) question ,-)

For my example, however, I will use **MVVM Light toolkit** which I recommend you to use as it will relief you from most of the MVVM annoyances that you will need to deal with in any real-world application.

You can get MVVM Light from NuGet:

```
Install-Package MvvmLight -Version 5.4.1
```

So now you can use MvvmLight implementation of `ICommand` which is called `RelayCommand`, you would do so in your ViewModel as follows:

```
[...]

public ICommand LoadedCommand { get; private set; }

public VendorsListViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base() {
    UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    CurrentPage = 1;
    ModelsPerPage = 25;
    LoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(this.Loaded);
}

private void Loaded()
{
    SetVendors();
}
```

As per your second question: absolutely, you can load the data asynchronously if you want to. This is a whole different question though,  take a look at this article for more info: https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to load the data using a command asynchronously.

Comment: If you could, please have a look a this other question. You may be able to answer it too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855438/how-to-add-a-delete-button-for-every-record-on-a-datagrid-using-wpf